# Collection.estimatedDocumentCount() not showing results

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

Good day,
I'm creating a social media app using MEAN stack which will contain an option to list the users you are following however, as per Collections.Find() has been deprecated, I was using Colletions.estimatedDocumentCount() to list the users in JSON (as currently I'm testing it using postman).

It shows the number of users and how many you are following however, there is no more data in the JSON to display.

This is my function. Any help will be very appreciated

```
function getFollowTest(req,res){

var userId = req.user.sub;

if (req.params.id) {
    user.id = req.params.id;
}

var page = 1;
if (req.params.page) {
    page = req.params.page;
}

var itemsPerPage = 4;

Follow.estimatedDocumentCount({user:userId})
                        .populate({path: 'followed'})
                        .paginate(page, itemsPerPage, (err, follows, total)=>{
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({message:'Server error'});

        if (!follows) return res.status(404).send({message:'you are not following any user'});

        res.status(200).send({
            total: total,
            pages: Math.ceil(total/itemsPerPage),
            follows
        });
});
```

}

This is how it looks in Postman: [image: Postman Output]

Comment: What is your problem? I saw the API returns the result.

Comment: Hi, it suppose to display the total, how many pages and the follows (which should display users id's, name, surname email, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `paginate()` incorrectly.

Check this:

```
const getPagination = (page, size) => {
  const limit = size ? +size : 3;
  const offset = page ? page * limit : 0;

  return { limit, offset };
};


const getFollowTest = async (req, res) => {

  var userId = req.user.sub;

  if (req.params.id) {
    user.id = req.params.id;
  }

  var page = 1;
  if (req.params.page) {
    page = req.params.page;
  }
  var itemsPerPage = 4;

  const { limit, offset } = getPagination(page, itemsPerPage);

  const result = await Follow.paginate({ user: userId }, { offset, limit });

  res.status(200).send({
    totalItems: result.totalDocs,
    tutorials: result.docs,
    totalPages: result.totalPages,
    currentPage: result.page - 1,
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Murat...I forgot to mention that when I run my code, the terminal shows this (node:2633) DeprecationWarning: collection.count is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. Use Collection.countDocuments or Collection.estimatedDocumentCount instead
so I think that the problem is that the Forms.find() is no longer working and I'm looking for an alternative. Thanks

Comment: @SecaidaDevStudent I don't really understand why do you want to use `find` and `count` ? Don't you need to paginate the results? Can you just copy and paste my answer and see the result..

Comment: Hi Murat..the goal here was just to display a JSON with Id's of people I'm following and also people who are following me so that is why I was using the find however when I ran it in the console, it says that the find function is deprecated and suggest to use the count but you know what? I figured out by adding something extra to my mongoose.connect() and now I can use the collections.find() with no problems...thank you for your help